# records less than average number of days between 2 columns

Tags: oracle, date, average

I'm trying to figure out how to select only the records which have less than average of number of days between the start_date and end_date.

I have 3 records in my table, I've tried so many ways with avg, but I don't seem to get it done. This is how the table (university) that I've created looks like:

> dep_id / class_id / start_date / end_date  / comments
>
> 7500   / 10050    / 10-FEB-10  / 20-FEB-10 / clean
>
> 7501   / 10060    / 17-MAR-10  / 22-MAR-10 / dirty
>
> 7502   / 10070    / 21-JUN-10  / 29-JUL-10 / clean

and this is what I've tried and got so far:

```
select dep_id, class_id, start_date, end_date, comments
from university
where dep_id = (select avg( cast(end_date as DATE) - cast(start_date as date)) as avg_days
from university);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT dep_id,class_id,start_date,end_date,comments
  FROM (
  SELECT t1.*,AVG(TO_DATE(end_date,'dd-mon-yy') - TO_DATE(start_date,'dd-mon-yy')) OVER() total_avg
  ,TO_DATE(end_date,'dd-mon-yy') - TO_DATE(start_date,'dd-mon-yy') diff  FROM university t1) q
  WHERE diff< total_avg
```